# Why is an error reported when the batch_size is set greater than 1 when paddle detection performs inference?

Tags: paddleocr

PaddleDetection:deploy/python/infer.py的batch_size设置>1遍报错
error message：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/zyp/program/pdf_ocr/PaddleDetection-release-2.6/deploy/python/infer.py", line 1097, in
    main()
File "/home/zyp/program/pdf_ocr/PaddleDetection-release-2.6/deploy/python/infer.py", line 1063, in main
    save_results=FLAGS.save_results)
File "/home/zyp/program/pdf_ocr/PaddleDetection-release-2.6/deploy/python/infer.py", line 413, in predict_image
    result = self.postprocess(inputs, result)
File "/home/zyp/program/pdf_ocr/PaddleDetection-release-2.6/deploy/python/infer.py", line 682, in postprocess
    np_boxes, np_boxes_num = postprocessor(np_score_list, np_boxes_list)
File "/home/zyp/program/pdf_ocr/PaddleDetection-release-2.6/deploy/python/picodet_postprocess.py", line 166, in call
    center = center[topk_idx]
IndexError: index 165237 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7600

model：picodet_lcnet_x1_0_fgd_layout_cdla_infer
```

I tried many times, it works normally when batch_size=1, but when batch_size > 1, the above error is reported, does anyone know why?

Comment: In the documentation of paddledetection, I found the following information:
Note: The Paddle prediction library version needs to be >=2.1, and batch_size>1 only supports YOLOv3 and PP-YOLO.

The model I use does not support batch_size>1